# Conditional Average from Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with multiple columns of real estate sales data. I would like to find the average price-per-square-foot `'ppsf'` for all 1bed-1bath sales by zip code. Here is my attempt (each key in the dict is a zip code):

```
bed1_bath1={}
for zip in zip_codes:
    bed1_bath1[zip]= (df.loc[(df['bed']==1) & (df['bath']==1) & (df['zip']==zip)]).mean()
```

The problem is that this adds the mean of all columns from the dataframe to the dictionary. I'm sure there is a better way to do this; maybe using numpy.where?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(df[(df['bed']==1) & (df['bath']==1) & (df['zip']==zip)])['ppsf'].mean()` would do it. You simply choose the column you are interested in before calculating the mean (so you will not even do the processing for the rest of the columns).